# forward stepwise regression

Tags: r, regression

In R stepwise forward regression, I specify a minimal model and a set of variables to add (or not to add):

```
min.model = lm(y ~ 1)
fwd.model = step(min.model, direction='forward', scope=(~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ...))
```

Is there any way to specify using all variables in a matrix/data.frame, so I don't have to enumerate them?

Examples to illustrate what I'd like to do, but they don't work:

```
# 1
fwd.model = step(min.model, direction='forward', scope=(~ ., data=my.data.frame))

# 2
min.model = lm(y ~ 1, data=my.data.frame)
fwd.model = step(min.model, direction='forward', scope=(~ .))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`scope` expects (quoting the help page `?step`)

> either a single formula, or a list containing
>             components ‘upper’ and ‘lower’, both formulae.  See the
>             details for how to specify the formulae and how they are
>             used.

You can extract and use the formula corresponding to "~." like this:

```
> my.data.frame=data.frame(y=rnorm(20),foo=rnorm(20),bar=rnorm(20),baz=rnorm(20))
> min.model = lm(y ~ 1, data=my.data.frame)
> biggest <- formula(lm(y~.,my.data.frame))
> biggest
y ~ foo + bar + baz
> fwd.model = step(min.model, direction='forward', scope=biggest)
Start:  AIC=0.48
y ~ 1

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS      AIC
+ baz   1    2.5178 16.015 -0.44421
<none>              18.533  0.47614
+ foo   1    1.3187 17.214  0.99993
+ bar   1    0.4573 18.075  1.97644

Step:  AIC=-0.44
y ~ baz

       Df Sum of Sq    RSS      AIC
<none>              16.015 -0.44421
+ foo   1   0.41200 15.603  1.03454
+ bar   1   0.20599 15.809  1.29688
>
```

Comment: Have you read about the vast amount of evidence that variable selection causes severe problems of estimation and inference?  At the very least, the stepwise approach should be bootstrapped to show its arbitrariness.

Comment: @FrankHarrell - where can I learn more about bootstrapping stepwise regression?

Comment: Http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms and look for course notes

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one step like this

```
fwd.model = step(lm(y ~ 1, data=my.data.frame), 
                 direction='forward', scope=~ x1 + x2 + x3 + ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `step` resembles the funciton `stepAIC` in MASS package, following is an example from `?stepAIC`

```
quine.stp <- stepAIC(quine.nxt,
    scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
    trace = FALSE)
```