# Trying to execute a stepwise forward regression, but I get an error?

Tags: r

```
DF_test <- structure(list(`2013` = c(1L, 0L, 1L), `2014` = c(0L, 0L, 2L), 
`2015` = c(0L, 0L, 1L), `2016` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), Sum = c(4, 
0, 5)), .Names = c("2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "Sum"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to do a forward stepwise regression as such:

```
step(lm(Sum~1, data=DF_test), direction="forward", scope=~ 2013 + 2014 + 2015 + 2016)
```

Unfortunately executing it generates the following error:

```
Error in terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE) : 

  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Can anybody explain to me what this error is and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you're using as your `scope` argument: `2013 + 2014 + 2015 + 2016` will be evaluated not as a formula referring to names of columns, but just a bunch of numbers being added. That's why it's generally good practice to not have names begin with numbers. You can escape it one of two ways: either use backticks when giving those names, or change the names so they begin with a letter instead. Since these are years, makes sense for them to start with "y".

```r
# with backticks
step(lm(Sum~1, data=DF_test), direction="forward", scope=~ `2013` + `2014` + `2015` + `2016`)

# with better names
names(DF_test)[1:4] <- paste0("y", names(DF_test)[1:4])

step(lm(Sum~1, data=DF_test), direction="forward", scope=~ y2013 + y2014 + y2015 + y2016)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to define the scope as a lm() object too.

```
step(lm(Sum~1,data=DF_test), direction="forward", scope= lm(Sum~.,data=DF_test)) #the "." means all variables
```

This code runs here but no variables are added. 
It could be because the example data is too simple.

Comment: scope is not an object but rather a formula. read about `?step` and you will see what scope it. He just did define the right hand side of the formula instead of the whole formula. Also there are not enough degrees of freedom in the data to compute all the coefficients of the variables since n<p.

Comment: Wrap the `lm` `scope` argument in `formula()`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22913775/2799941).